# ERROR: We can't change the netmask of a Google Cloud virtual machine when we create a new one using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, ip-address, terraform-provider-gcp, netmask

Where doing a school project trying to do topologies using Google Cloud as the cloud and Terraform as the way to administrate every aspect of the virtual machine and network creation. When we try to assign IP address on the machines we get a default netmask (/32) every time we try to create a new machine even when we are giving guidelines on the code to give us a /24.
This is the configuration of the network and subnetworks on the main.tf:

```
`resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
    name = "t-network-hyperion"
    auto_create_subnetworks = false

    // Agregar la configuración de IP
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet_network" {
    name          = "subnet-hyperion"
    network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link
    ip_cidr_range = "192.168.0.0/24"  // Aquí especificamos la máscara /24

    region = "us-central1"
}
`

We tried changing the net mask using /16, /24, /28.
Every time we have changed the configuration we have destroyed the previews version and created new ones but it never changes. We are using this version of the provider:
terraform {
    required_providers {
        google = {
            source = "hashicorp/google"
            version = "4.57.0"
        }
    }
}
```

We’re struggling because we don’t know well what could be the solution. Any help may help us to get a solution on this topic. If anybody need to see more part of the code we would be on line.

Comment: I am not certain what you are trying to accomplish with the netmask. What type of IP address are you assigning? Normally, DHCP allocates an IP address to a VM's network interface. The netmask is read from the DHCP server. Even if you could change the netmask, on the next DHCP refresh, the netmask would be updated by DHCP. Your question does not show the steps you are following to set the IP address, what is being set, the results, etc. Note: VM network interfaces can have two IP addresses: the internal VPC address and a public IP address that is actually assigned to a special 1-to-1 NAT.